# Finding a path Scheme

Tags: path, scheme, racket

I am new to Scheme and today I came across the following problem that I couldn't solve. I have the following representation for the nodes of a tree representing a file system:

(directory_name content) for directories
file_name for files
(directory_name null) for an empty directory

For example, ("etc/" (("network/" ("interfaces")))) is the tree for path etc/network/interfaces.

What I have to do is to write a function that takes as arguments this kind of tree and a directory/file name and returns the path to it, if there is one. If the directory/file doesn't exist, it returns #f.

For example:

```
(define tree '("/"
               (("etc/" ("network/" ("interfaces")))
                ("root/" null))))
```

Supposing the function's name is get-path, by running (get-path tree "interfaces") it will output "/etc/network/interfaces".

All I want is an idea, if you can give me one, I will be grateful.

Comment: Do a depth first search. I.e. if the first element in the data structure is what you search for: return it, otherwise, search each child in turn (recursively).

Comment: How do you want to handle multiple paths?  That is 'interfaces' might exist multiple times in different paths: /dev/interfaces, /etc/interfaces.

Comment: @GoZoner Since it wasn't specified in the problem that I can have multiple paths, I assume there are no multiple paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer for you.  I used symbols not strings for directory/files and slightly changed the tree format.

```
(define tree '(root (etc (passwd) (profile)) (usr (bin) (lib))))

(define (get-path tree name)
  (define (reverse-if l) (and l (reverse l)))
  (reverse-if
   (let descending ((tree tree) (path '()))
     (and (not (null? tree))
          (let ((root (car tree))
                (subs (cdr tree)))
            (if (eq? root name)
                (cons root path)
                (let looking ((subs subs))
                  (and (not (null? subs))
                       (or (descending (car subs) (cons root path))
                           (looking (cdr subs)))))))))))
```

With some results:

```
> (get-path tree 'etc)
(root etc)
> (get-path tree 'bin)
(root usr bin)
> (get-path tree 'profile)
(root etc profile)
> (get-path tree 'foo)
#f
>
```